# SQL syntax error - multiple values from two tables & insert total

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need some help with the query below - I am trying to pull information regarding price and multiply with the quantity & insert the sum into the table. So far I have,

```
update passenger_baggage 
SET passenger_baggage.total_baggage_cost=passenger_baggage.passenger_baggage_quantity*baggage_type.baggage_type_cost
FROM passenger_baggage INNER JOIN baggage_type
ON passenger_baggage.passenger_baggage_id = baggage_type.baggage_type_id
WHERE  passenger_id = "3";
```

and getting this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FROM passenger_baggage INNER JOIN baggage_type ON
> passenger_baggage.passenge...' at line 3

Expecting the query to multiply the two values & insert the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` query.

Try with this modified query:

```
update passenger_baggage
INNER JOIN baggage_type
ON passenger_baggage.passenger_baggage_id = baggage_type.baggage_type_id 
SET passenger_baggage.total_baggage_cost = passenger_baggage.passenger_baggage_quantity * baggage_type.baggage_type_cost
WHERE  passenger_id = "3";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE passenger_baggage, baggage_type 
SET passenger_baggage.total_baggage_cost = passenger_baggage.passenger_baggage_quantity * baggage_type.baggage_type_cost 
WHERE passenger_baggage.passenger_baggage_id = baggage_type.baggage_type_id AND passenger_id = "3";
```

Saw an example from the MySQL doc (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).